# How to prove the divergence of a infinite product?

Tags: divergent-series, infinite-product, divergence-operator

I'm trying to prove the divergence of $$\prod_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{(-1)^{k}}{\sqrt{k}}\right)$$ which would be the same as proving the divergence of $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{(-1)^{k}}{\sqrt{k}}\right)$$ but I'm a bit lost. Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: Use the Taylor expansion of $\log (1+x)$ to order 3. You'll meet something harmonic.

Comment: I like this one. The series looks *so* much like it should converge as an alternating series! I'll try to remember this next time I teach series.

Comment: @DanielFischer order 2 gives the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join terms together in pairs:
$$ \log\Bigl(1+\frac1{\sqrt{2j}}\Bigr) + \log\Bigl(1-\frac1{\sqrt{2j+1}}\Bigr)
  = \log\Bigl(1+\frac{\sqrt{2j+1}-\sqrt{2j}-1}{\sqrt{2j(2j+1)}}\Bigr)
$$
which behaves like $-1/\sqrt{2j(2j+1)}\sim-1/(2j)$ when $j\to\infty$ (since $-1$ dominates the difference of square roots in the final numerator).

Comment: I think you cannot join terms since it is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima: Joining terms is no problem: The partial sums of the new series are partial sums of the original series (with an even number of terms). The only additional requirement is for the terms to go to zero, and they do.

Answer (score 1):

Near zero,
$$\ln (1+X)=X-\frac {X^2}{2}(1+\epsilon (X)) $$
thus

Near infinity,

$$\ln (1+\frac {(-1)^k}{\sqrt {k}})=$$

$$\frac {(-1)^k}{\sqrt {k}}-\frac {1}{2k}(1+\epsilon (k)) $$

the first series $\sum \frac {(-1)^k}{\sqrt {k}} $ is convergent as an alternate.

the second $\sum \frac {1}{2k}(1+\epsilon (k)) $ is divergent since it is equivalent to $\sum \frac {1}{2k} $.

as a sum of a convergent and a divergent series, you series is divergent.